# Display Spreadsheet Data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dom-events

I have a problem with my HTML Table. I want my spreadsheet data to be displayed there. I don't know what did I missed.

This is my Code.GS:

```js
function getTableData(){
  var url3 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0";
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url3);
  var ws3 = ss3.getSheetByName("Time");
  var data = ws3.getRange(2,2,ws3.getLastRow()-1,10).getValues();
  //Logger.log(data);
  return data;

}
```

This is my Script:

```html
 <script>

var data = [
    [1, "Jack",55],
    [1, "Jack",55],
    [1, "Jack",55]
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();


});

function generateTable(dataArray){

var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

dataArray.forEach(function(r){

var row = document.createElement("tr");
var col1 = document.createElement("td");
col1.textContent = r[0];
var col2 = document.createElement("td");
col2.textContent = r[1];
var col3 = document.createElement("td");
col3.textContent = r[2];
row.appendChild(col1);
row.appendChild(col2);
row.appendChild(col3);
tbody.appendChild(row);
});

}

</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>E-mail</th>
                  <th>Case</th>
                  <th>Assignment</th>
                  <th>Notes</th>
                  <th>Start Date</th>
                  <th>Start Time</th>
                  <th>End Date</th>
                  <th>End Time</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="table-body">
             
            </tbody>
            
          </table>
```

I almost pulled my hair off, I am frustrated. I tried everything I know but no luck. Can you help?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please describe what works and what don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an old piece of code that I used to get all of my Spreadsheets.  Give it a chance to run as it takes a while to load all of the spreadsheets at first.  It also allows you to edit all of the sheets as well.  I'm guessing that you'll be able to figure out how you can use this example to figure how to solve your problem.

htmlss.hmtl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#msg').html('Please wait. Collecting a list of all Spreadsheets...');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
         .getAllSpreadSheets();
    });

    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      var ssId=$('#sel1').val();
      var name=$('#sel2').val();
      var updObj={rowIndex:i,colIndex:j,value:value,id:ssId,name:name};
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(updateSheet)
         .updateSpreadsheet(updObj);
    }

    function updateSheet(data)
    {
      //$('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }

    function updateSelect(dtO)
    {
      $('#sel1').css('background','#ffffff');
      $('#sel2').css('background','#ffffff');
      $('#msg').html('Spreadsheet List has been updated.  Now select a SpreadSheet to display');
      var select = document.getElementById(dtO.type);
      var vA=dtO.array;
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][0],vA[i][vA[i].length-1]);
      }
    }

    function loadSelectSheet()
    {
       var shId=$('#sel1').val();
       var name=$('#sel1').text();
       $('#sel1').css('background','#ffff00');
       document.getElementById('ssname').innerHTML="";
       var ssO={name:name ,id:shId}
       google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
           .getAllSheets(ssO);

    }

    function displaySelectedSheet()
    {
       var ssId=$('#sel1').val();
       var name=$('#sel2').val();
       $('#sel2').css('background','#ffff00');
       document.getElementById('shname').innerHTML="";
       var ssO={id:ssId,name:name};
       google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(displaySheet)
           .htmlSpreadsheet(ssO);
    }

    function displaySheet(opO)
    {
        $('#sel2').css('background','#ffffff');
        document.getElementById('ssname').innerHTML=opO.name;
        document.getElementById('shname').innerHTML=opO.shname;
        document.getElementById('sss').innerHTML=opO.hl;
    }

    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="msg"></div><br />
  <br /><select id="sel1" onChange="loadSelectSheet();"></select>
  <br /><select id="sel2" onChange="displaySelectedSheet();"></select>
  <div id="ssname"></div>
  <div id="shname"></div>
  <div id="sss"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function htmlSpreadsheet(ssO) {
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssO.id);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(ssO.name);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="20" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="20" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  var namehl=Utilities.formatString('<h1>%s</h1>', ss.getName());
  var shnamehl=Utilities.formatString('<h2>%s</h2>', sht.getName());
  var opO={hl:s,name:namehl,shname:shnamehl};
  return opO;
}

function updateSpreadsheet(updObj) {
  var i=updObj.rowIndex;
  var j=updObj.colIndex;
  var value=updObj.value;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(updObj.id);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(updObj.name);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
  return userInterface.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function getAllSpreadSheets() {
  var files=DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); 
  var s = '';
  var vA=[['Select Spreadsheet',0]];
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName=file.getName();
    var fileId=file.getId();
    vA.push([fileName,fileId]);
  }
  //return vA;
  return {array:vA,type:'sel1'};
}

//working on this function right now 2017/11/08
function getAllSheets(ssO) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssO.id);
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var vA=[['Select Sheet']];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var name=allSheets[i].getName();
    vA.push([name]);
  }
  return {array:vA,type:'sel2'};
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a standalone webapp.