# How to read Google sheet cells and display it to an HTML form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

This will be deployed as a web app, and I need to get a range of values from a Google sheet document and display it on my HTML form.

I need to get the cell values from the temp variable and pass it to the text forms. So far, I have the code for the app script, but I don't know how to pass it to the HTML forms.

Code.gs //Code for the Google App script

```
function getValues() 
{

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var temp = activeSheet.getRange("A1:C1").getValues();

  Logger.log(temp); //I need to get the values from the temp variable and pass it to the text forms.
}
```

Index.html //HTML index page

```
<form>
  A1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="a1" value="">
  <br>

  B1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="b1" value="">
  <br>

  C1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="b1" value="">

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Fetch">
</form>
```

Comment: I think this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56479763/7215091

Comment: Here's another example for a webapp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819742/7215091.  You can also do it with html templates and scriplets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is how you can do it

> GS file

```
function getValues() 
{

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var temp = activeSheet.getRange("A1:C1").getValues();       
  return temp;
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate()
}
```

> HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <? var temp = getValues(); ?>  
  <form>
  A1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="a1" value=" <?= temp[0][0] ?> ">
  <br>
  B1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="b1" value=" <?= temp[0][1] ?> ">
  <br>
  C1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="b1" value=" <?= temp[0][2] ?> ">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Fetch">
  </form> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

The printing scriplets `<? ?>` allow you to evaluate Apps Script variables inside the HTML code, you could even directly access Spreadsheet contents within the printing scriplets. Please find [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) more information to printing scriplets.