# How to use JavaScript to pull Google Spreadsheet data into HTML within Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a script in Google Sheets that will pop up a form with fields based on data in the sheet, then create an email draft when the form is submitted.

I'm using Google Apps Script to generate an HTML form. The form fields need to be generated from data in the sheet (e.g. a dropdown menu with options from a range in the sheet).

Here's what I'm putting in my HTML:

```
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Value = Sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Value;
  </script>
```

...But the area of the form where the string should show up is blank.

As a point of reference, this works:

```
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    var Moment = Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Moment;
  </script>
```

When I include the second script, it successfully displays the date string.

So, what is it about SpreadsheetApp (or something coming after that) that isn't working here?

I'm very new to JS, etc., so help is much appreciated :) Thanks!!!

Comment: These are server side commands `var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Value = Sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();`  they go into .gs files in the script editor [Learn More Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)...these are Javascript commands `var Moment = Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Moment;`  they go between `<script></script>` tags in an html file [Learn More Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6)

Comment: [Displaying Spreadsheet Data in html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819742/7215091)

Answer (score 0):

The second code works because you're using a pure Javascript function in an HTML file, which in between  can be executed by your browser and works like a charm.

The first code does not work because you're calling an apps script function, which certainly it uses Javascript, but it's not pure Javascript. It can not be rendered on the browser as a common Javascript because Apps Script is rendered on google servers and so you have to use another syntax.

But it's possible to make it and it is simple, there are three ways:

- Calling Apps Script functions from HTML templates
- Calling Apps Script API's directly from HTML templates
- Pushing variables from the Apps Script to the HTML templates

I'll show here an example of what you were trying, it is the second option: 
Basically you just have to change:

`<script> var myvar = ... </script>` for `<? var myvar = ... />`

And when displaying variables use

`<?= myvar ?>`

**Calling Apps Script functions from a template:**

```html
  <? var value = SpreadsheetApp.openById("FILE_ID").getSheets()[0].getRange("E2").getValue(); ?>
  <p><?= value ?></p>
```

Just make to call evaluate() when rendering the html file from appscript

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html').evaluate();
}
```

On here you'll find the three ways to make this explained:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#calling_apps_script_functions_from_a_template