# Display a editable Google Sheet on a web page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to display an editable Google Sheet on a web page.
No problem for that.
The problem: I want to display this sheet without the menus, columns and lines. Is it possible ?
Or display the sheet in full screen mode, but I do not know the javascript function to execute when opening the sheet.
Ex.: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xwheykkZMb806JKNoPGcVl17TpIm4Z9LTLJb8HAhVVk/edit?usp=sharing
How to do ?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819742/7215091)  This is a standalone web app that allows me to edit any spread in my account.  It takes a while to load the spreadsheet select options so be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Publish to the Web.

And then, you will see this kind of pop up. You can publish it and also get the link. Google Slide and Docs also have this feature. As you can see it, you can also get embed tag for inserting it in HTML. You can stop publishing with the `Stop publishing` button whenever you want.

[image]

And as far as I know, there is no such thing that you can edit the file with that mode.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Indeed, like this, the sheet cannot be modified. But I want it to be editable so that users can access the drop-down lists in the sheet ...
how to not display the G-sheet interface but only the sheet?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen any cases? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: No, nothing seen ... Now I also believe that it is impossible.