# How do I embed a truly live Google Sheets spreadsheet into a webpage?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, embed

## What I want

A website which displays the truly live sheet (updating instantly when the sheet is changed from elsewhere, like in the editor), but centered on the screen and without menus etc. (like in 2b)

Specifically a website which

- shows a sheet of a Google Sheets spreadsheet, correctly formatted
- updates the sheet live without any user input around once a second
- does not contain Google Sheets editing headers
- centeres the content in the page and has a black border to fill the screen outside of the spreadsheet

## What I know

After many Google searches, I have found two results lining my goal:

### 1. Google Sheets editor without menu

[image: example]

You can directly display the sheet within the editor by simple adding `?rm=minimal` to the url as in

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/view?rm=minimal#gid=SHEET_ID`

This

- updates the data truly live, whenever the sheet is changed

but

- shows row and column headers (A, B, C, ..., 1, 2, 3, ...)
- shows sheet selection and "insert x rows below"
- is not centered and does not have a black background

### 2. This other URL thing

[image: example]

When you edit the URL and replace `/edit...` with `/htmlembed/sheet?gid=SHEET_ID` like in

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/SPREADSHEET_ID/htmlembed/sheet?gid=SHEET_ID`

This

- does not contain any headers or similar
- even allows me to specify only a fixed range to be displayed using the `range=A1NOTATION` parameter

It can be extended using a GScript WebApp:

### 2b. GScript WebApp

[image: example]
(Note that I used green instead of black for visualisation)

Using this URL within a GScript `doGet(e)` function published as a WebApp allows me to customise it further. I simply added a style-tag to the original source and used background-color as well as flex display to set the background and center the content. This is my function, WHICH IS VERY VULNERABLE TO HTML INJECTION:

```
function doGet(e) {
  // Getting spreadsheet app
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Getting sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monitor " + e.parameter.monitor);
  //Return error if specified sheet does not exist
  if (sheet == null)
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>Invalid monitor id \"" + e.parameter.monitor + "\"</b> pass as ?monitor=MONITOR");

  // Generating the URL
  var publishedURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/" + ss.getId() + "/htmlembed/sheet?range=a3:z&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();

  // Fetching the site
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(publishedURL, {'muteHttpExceptions': true}).getContentText();

  // Getting the background color from paramter (default is black)
  var bg = e.parameter.bg;
  if (bg == null)
    var bg = "black";

  // Defining the styling (I know this way is lazy)
  var styling = "<style>\
body, div {\
background-color: " + bg + " !important;\
display: flex;\
justify-content: center;\
align-items: center;\
}\
</style>";

  // Returning the webpage from original data combined with styling
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response+styling);
}
```

This is further centered in the page and has a black border to fill the screen outside of the spreadsheet

But the URL-approach has a really significant drawback: It does not update every second, but only if the page is refreshed

## What I then tried

#### Refreshing the webpage every second thru html or js

This should work, but since the page loads "so slowly", I would see a blank page half of the time, if I refresh every second

#### Fetching the URL from the client

Utilising the js `fetch` function, I could fetch the source on the client in the background which would then update quicker, but I ran into a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) issue in that Google won't let me fetch the source when the request comes from the client. (It does work, when I fetch it within the GScript.)

#### Fetching the source from the client via the WebApp

My last resolution was to fetch the source from the WebApp, which intern fetches it from the spreadsheet, but apparently I can't allow CORS for the WebApp.

## What I don't know

How do I get the middleground which a) instantly updates and b) is well formatted?

Is there something else I can do with the URL? Like
`/htmlembed` or

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=0`

as described [in this medium post](https://medium.com/@stvhwrd/embedding-a-google-sheet-as-an-html-table-365306d2ec2c)

Comment: I have a webapp that allows me to access and edit any of my spreadsheets via an html table.  I supposed one could add the ability to store a log of spreadsheets edits and update each cell every time the clientside poll initiates that action.  Here's a link to it. [html spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819742/7215091) You're welcome to try.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately this is the wrong way around, I want to update the website whenever the spreadsheet is changed. In this case I don't have a clientside trigger

Comment: Every cell in the HTML is addressable so it would be easy to add updating the html from the spreadsheet via a client side polling source and google.script.run client to server communication but yes it’s not complete you would have to write it yourself

Comment: If the sheet is publicly shared, try framing the url2b instead of fetching it. ``<iframe src="url"></iframe>``

Comment: @TheMaster I tried using an `iframe`, but I am also styling the result with a `style` tag so that won't work. The `srcdoc` property overwrites the `src` property, so using it does not work either

Comment: 1.Why do you want to style it? 2.How will the scores change in Google sheets?

Comment: 1) The sheet is supposed to be displayed on a screen and this should only display the information, no heders, etc. and it should be centered. So I only style stuff outside of the actual sheet 2) I thought of making a button which adds a line to an event log. Then you could get the score by using a sum function. But let's assume it is changed by someone entering a number at a specified location on the sheet

Comment: Cache the ``response``> Every second, only if `response` is different  than previous  cached response, reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this by caching the response of the fetch function and only refreshing the page if it has changed, like @TheMaster suggested. I also added a simple hash function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490015/11500248) and used a regular expression to secure the code a bit against HTML-injection.

The following code will refresh the page a soon as the last update has finished (approx. every second). This is still slower then in the editor, so you may want to use solution 1 in the original question.

**monitor.gs**

```
/**
 * Only needs acced to the spredsheet the code is installed in
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("frame");
}


// Fetching the live content from URL
function fetchContent(publishedURL, e) {
  // Fetching the site
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(publishedURL, {'muteHttpExceptions': true}).getContentText();

  // Getting the background color from paramter (default is black)
  var bg = e.parameter.bg;
  if (bg == null)
    var bg = "black";

  // Creating and returning the response
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("style");
  template.bg = /\w+/.exec(bg)[0]; // Setting the background-color
  return template.evaluate().append(response);
}

// Returns the live content if it has cahnged, null otherways
function getContent(e, currentHash) {
  // Getting spreadsheet app
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Getting sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monitor " + e.parameter.monitor);
  //Return error if specified sheet does not exist
  if (sheet == null)
    return {content: "<b>Invalid monitor id \"" + /\w+/.exec(e.parameter.monitor)[0] + "\"</b> pass as ?monitor=MONITOR"};

  // Generating the URL
  var publishedURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/" + ss.getId() + "/htmlembed/sheet?range=a3:z&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();

  // Returning the content if it is different, null otherways
  var content = fetchContent(publishedURL, e).getContent();
  var hash = strhash(content);
  if (hash == currentHash)
    return null;
  Logger.log(hash);
  return {content: content, hash: hash};
}
```

(Also append [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490015/11500248))

**frame.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  let currentContent = undefined;
  function updateContent(content) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html")
  let sheets_viewport = doc.getElementById("sheets-viewport");

  console.log("Current hash: " + currentContent);
  if (content !== null) {
  document.open();
  document.write(content.content);
  document.close();

  console.log("refreshed.");
  currentContent = content.hash;
  console.log("New hash: " + currentContent);
  } else
  console.log("Nothing to refresh.");

  refresh();
  }
  function go(location) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateContent).getContent(location, currentContent);
  }
  refresh();
  function refresh() {console.log("refreshing..."); google.script.url.getLocation(go);}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div>
<p>Loading...</p>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.html**

```html
<style>
body, div {
background-color: <?= bg ?> !important;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
</style>
```