# Is there a way to choose spreadsheetID, name, range and cell thru HTML ; during the runtime of script (GAS) and then enter the value of that cell?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to enter data in a spreadsheet through apps script.
I have created an html form and till now everything is working fine~ Please see code below.

However, I have a spreadsheet which is already formatted like

Date in columns and columns with rows a b c d:

[image]

What I have done now is receiving response from html in GAS and record it in google sheets.
But in code.gs, through HTML (like a drop down/onchange) I want to point at a particular sheetID, then sheet Name, then Range and then I want to change the value of cell in Column E Row 63.

Comment: Your code is missing. Also, can you share a copy of the spreadsheet? I am wondering what the format of the date cells is.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vrV32Zy2I9lpALQRWKTOFa82On_yJNIO675jZ7R6TI4/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the sheet~
Data cell format is "number".

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56819742/7215091) might help:

Comment: @Cooper This code is not working. As I can see; it is to bring all spreadsheets in html, However what I only want is some part of a sheet in HTML.
Please help me!~~

Comment: It's not meant to be copied and utilized as is.  It's meant to be used as a reference example.  That example has to do many of the same things that your script will have to do and if some are left out then that will be left up to you to extrapolate from what you have learned from what is covered.